# Can I integrate Beyond Compare as an "External Diff" tool from Sublime Merge

Tags: integration, beyondcompare, sublimemerge

I love Sublime Merge, and I love Beyond Compare; however they don't seem to work together similar to Source Tree and Beyond Compare do.

Is there a way I can integrate those so that I can Ctrl Select two branches in Sublime Merge and analyse compare its file differences in  Beyond Compare?

Tried exploring Settings/Preferences/Diff, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Sublime Merge doesn't support external diff/merge tools, it's an open item in their issue tracker.

Sublime Merge Issues: [Support external diff/merge tool #58](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_merge/issues/58)